# Execute functions for external html file

Tags: javascript, html, function, load, external

I am trying to execute functions for external file. These functions in a scripts.js file and this is already loaded in the page. And i couldn't execute again them for external html files. Here is example for scripts

```
function contentInit(){
   $("[data-background]").each(function () {
      var bgSRC = $(this).data('background');
      $(this).css({
         'background-image': 'url(' + bgSRC + ')'
      }); 
   });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   contentInit();
});
```

and loading html files like this;

```
$('.loader-item').each(function(){
   var item = $(this),
       project = $(item).data('project');
   $(item).on('click', function(e){
      $("#project-loader").load(project, function() {
           contentInit();
      });
   });
});
```

Here is an example html;

```
<div class="loader-item" data-project="example-project.html"></div>
```

There is too much functions like data-background in the contentInit. And they don't work when an external page loaded. How to execute them? Or there is another way for this case?

Comment: You did not post any HTML with data-background

Comment: Approach shown is basically correct. Not really clear what the specific problem is though